# Laravel ORM get specific data from related model

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-8

I'm working on a Laravel 8 project which has `Content` and `Media` models and database tables. `Content` can have multiple media files while each `Media` belongs to a single content.

My `Media` model looks like this

```
class Media extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'content_id',
        'path',
        'media_type',
        'is_featured',
    ];

    public function content()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Content::class);
    }
}
```

In `Content` model I have relation:

```
public function media()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Media::class);
}
```

What I want to do is to create a function that will return just a `path` value of featured media for a Content so I can do something like:

```
$img_src = Content::find(1)->featuredImage;
```

Where should I put *featuredImage* function? Can I do that in the model? I tried making relation like this:

```
public function featuredImage()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Media::class)->where('is_featured','=',true)->where('media_type', '=', 'image');
}
```

But this returns the entire `Media` object. How can I get only `path` value or any other custom data structure?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `featuredImage()` method uses the `hasOne` eloquent method, it should only ever return one `Media` object. Because of that, you should be able to just do something like this:

```
public function featuredImage()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Media::class)
                ->where('is_featured','=',true)
                ->where('media_type', '=', 'image')
                ->path;
}
```

so all you were missing was the `->path` part of the query. You're getting the media object, and then once you have the media object, you just need to get the path. That way, when you call `$thing->featuredImage()` it will return `/some/path/from/media/object` and you should be good to go!

**Edit:** Don't forget to use the `featuredImage()` as a method call, not a property access, because the `featuredImage` property doesn't necessarily exist on the model, instead you are calling a method that defines the relationship between two models and returns a property from the `Media` model.